# Stuck in a Login Loop

Tags: raspbian, login

I was working on my Pi 3 last night and then logged out and when I went to log in again, the screen goes black like it is logging in, but it just returns to the login screen.

I know the password is right because I can get into the terminal, plus if I intentionally enter the wrong PW, it tells me incorrect PW.

For what it's worth, last night I was installing rdesktop for RDP, XRDP which includes TightVNCserver, and Remmina (none of which worked, by the way).

I have tried the following:

```
Checked permissions of Xauthority
Running FSCK
Checked permissions of /tmp
reconfigure lightdm
```

...Possibly others too, I have been on a bunch of forums

Here's the log from /var/log/syslog from one of my attempts at logging in...is it something to do with the org.freedesktop.accounts error? Please, any assitance would be appreciated!!!

```
Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole lightdm[903]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 109...

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopped target Default.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[1]: Started Session c6 of user pi.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopped target Basic System.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopped target Paths.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopped target Sockets.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (access for web browsers).

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Stopped target Timers.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Reached target Shutdown.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Starting Exit the Session...

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[827]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 986 (kill).

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole lightdm[540]: Error opening audit socket: Protocol not supported

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 109.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.

Oct 23 12:06:58 PiHole systemd[935]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.

Oct 23 12:06:59 PiHole lightdm[540]: Error opening audit socket: Protocol not supported

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole lightdm[1044]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of lightdm.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1]: Started Session c7 of user lightdm.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 109...

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (access for web browsers).

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Reached target Paths.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Reached target Timers.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Reached target Sockets.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Reached target Basic System.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Reached target Default.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Startup finished in 69ms.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 109.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole dbus-daemon[1064]: Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service'

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole dbus-daemon[1064]: Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'

Oct 23 12:07:00 PiHole systemd[1048]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
```

Comment: Solved the issue following instructions below !!! Very simple https://amalgjose.com/2020/03/31/raspberry-pi-desktop-gui-unable-to-login/comment-page-1/?unapproved=5023&moderation-hash=0551536ce2b1a297b1472f8888a3ba48#comment-5023

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem while working with something related with boot. You have two options :
1. Flash the sdcard again with new raspbian
2. Find another PC.reset everything by editing config and boot related texts.
I had to choose option 1 because I didn't knew it by then.

Comment: I just wish I could figure out the issue and fix it.  I’ll admit I’m not great with Linux even after switching to it a couple years ago. I thought that Linux was supposed to be solid overall and not fickle like this.  Although again I could have just screwed it up all by myself

Comment: No no do,t think like that. Actually sometimes we mess things up by playing with dependencies. That is a very common problem even I had done it. Think very carefully bfore doing something next time